# Improving build time for our create-react-app which is getting big

Tags: reactjs, build, continuous-integration, create-react-app, continuous-deployment

We are working on an application that uses create-react-app as its initial boilerplate. As the project is getting larger in size, the deployment is getting longer. For now, we are using gitlab runners to deploy it into AWS.

The problem is getting worse and it is now taking around 30minutes to build and deploy. I am seeking any advice on how to improve the performance and speed of the build time.

We have already tried using cache for the npm install part, but was not really successful. I also looked into incremental build but could not find a satisfying solution there.

We also explored the code splitting, but do not think that it affects the build time as it mainly impacts the run-time loading speed.

We are open to any practical solution such as changing bundler, runners, etc. and I am personaly interested in the success stories of those who tackled this problem so that we don't do trial and error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing static images from your project, large images can be a problem for your build time and deploy time for server.

If you really need to keep static images in your project, you can try to check and optimize the size of the images using a tool like (https://tinypng.com/). But I really recommend that you using a storage (AWS S3, for example) to store your images.

You can also try to remove big dependencies like, react-icons (or any other like this), Charts (like Charts.js...) can also be a problem for your build time.